Download Gradle
Whenever I creat a new project in Android studio, it starts downloading grafle version for it,  when I creat another it downloads the same gradle version file! is that normal? I am new in developing android apps
I downloaded gradle version and made environment variables and put the correct gradle file path in the settings put it doesn't work


In above picture, gradle file version is mention for the project.
if the gradle file version mention in the project is download already in default gradle download folder, it will not download new gradle. It will simply loaded it to the project.
and If version is change mention in the project, then it will download first and then loaded in the project.
Default gradle folder is below:



What does your gradle-wrapper.properties file look like?
It should look like this:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.7-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

8.7 is the latest Gradle. Change this to the version of Gradle you are using now.

ah, I noticed that I am using gradle 8.6
